# React-Native Project shows "...Print: Entry, "CFBundleIdentifier" does not exit" error after removing font files

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am working on react-native project ( react-native: 0.55.3, react-native:16.3.2). 
I removed old font files from assets folder and contents from XCODE's info tab' Fonts provided by application item. 
 After cleaning cache, it shows "...Print: Entry, "CFBundleIdentifier" does not exit" error.
I tried to reinstall node modules. but still shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also remove the font dependencies from following setting path?

> XCODE's Build Phase/ Copy Bundle Resources

There must be old font dependencies. please open Xcode and delete them from above mentioned project setting path.

Comment: No problem. Not found CFBundleIdentifier error also appears in other cases, so you need to check terminal logs first. If not found, try to run XCODE project, and check logs.